# Pandas: Merge a dataframe column to a list

Tags: python, pandas, merge, nltk

i am doing some Text Analysis with Python (Nltk, Pandas) and need some help with my Dataframe. I am still a programming beginner.

I have a PoS Tagged Dataframe(1000 rows, 5 columns).

Column names: Number(this in the Index), Id, Title, Question, Answers

```
#2 Example rows for Question:

[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('working', 'VERB'),('website', 'NOUN')]
[('Would', 'VERB'), ('you', 'PRON'), ('recomme...)] 

#2 Example rows for Answers:

[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('not', 'ADV'),('website', 'NOUN')] 
[('There', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('a', 'DET'...)]
```

Goals:

1.) **one** **list** (not str) with all 1000 PoS Tagged Questions

2.) **one** **list** (not str) with all 1000 PoS Tagged Answers

3.) **one** **list** (not str) with all 1000 PoS Tagged Answers and Questions

What i tried so far is to merge all rows in the Question column  but my result was like:

```
[[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'),..],[('Would', 'VERB'), 
('you', 'PRON'), ('recomme...)],[(.....)]]
```

I guess i made a mistake with joining them. how can i do this correctly to achieve a list which looks like this:

```
[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('working', 'VERB'),.....]
```

for the complete column.

**Edit after Beneres answer:**

Thx for your quick answer.
.sum() was my approach i did before but the result is:

```
print (df['Merged'])
0      [('Does', 'NOUN'), ('anyone', 'NOUN'), ('know'...
1      [('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('building', '...
2      [('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('wondering', ...
3      [('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('working', 'V...
```

What i need is

```
print (df['Merged'])
0      [('Does', 'NOUN'), ('anyone', 'NOUN'), ('know'...
        ('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('building', '...
        ('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('wondering', ...
        ('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB'), ('working', 'V...]
```

**Edit 2:**
solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a weird way, don't know if this is a good solution but it works:

```
from ast import literal_eval

# sum all columns and replace resulting "][" between columns with ", "
# change str to list with literal_eval
allQuestions = literal_eval(dfQuestion.sum().replace("][", " ,"))
allAnswers = literal_eval(dfAnswers.sum().replace("][", " ,"))
allPosts = allQuestions + allAnswers
```

I hope this can help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you just need to do:

```
df['Merged'] = df['Questions'] + df['Answers']
```

which merges questions and answers, and then do

```
df.sum()
```

which merges (sums) all lists.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q':[[('I', 'PRON'), ('am', 'VERB')], [('You', 'PRON'), ('are', 'VERB')]], 
              'A':[[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB')], [('Sparta', 'NOUN'), ('bitch', 'VERB')]]})
df['Merged'] = df['A'] +df['Q']
```

then:

```
df.sum()
```

looks like this:

```
A         [(This, DET), (is, VERB), (Sparta, NOUN), (bit...
Q         [(I, PRON), (am, VERB), (You, PRON), (are, VERB)]
Merged    [(This, DET), (is, VERB), (I, PRON), (am, VERB...
dtype: object
```

Then I am not quite sure about the format for goal 3, please give more details if this is not what you want.